# OpenGL point sprites render as points and not textures

Tags: c++, image, opengl, textures

Here's my code

vertex shader

```
#version 430

in vec3 position;
uniform mat4 MVP;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = MVP * vec4(position, 1.0);
}
```

fragment shader

```
#version 430

out vec4 outputColor;
uniform sampler2D tex;

void main()
{
    outputColor = texture(tex, gl_PointCoord);
}
```

init

```
void init()
{
    glPointSize(20.0f);
    GLuint tex;
    glGenTextures(1, &tex);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    bmp.Open("C:\\users\\alon\\desktop\\star.bmp");
    bmp.ReadPixels();
    unsigned char *pixels = new unsigned char[bmp.NeededBufferSize()];
    bmp.AssignPixels(pixels);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, bmp.GetWidth(), bmp.GetHeight(), 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
    delete[] pixels;

    glClearColor(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);

    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    GLuint VaoId;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VaoId);
    glBindVertexArray(VaoId);

    position_index = glGetAttribLocation(program, "position");
    MVP_location = glGetUniformLocation(program, "MVP");

    //                      x      y      z     s     t
    GLfloat vertices[] = {-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
                           0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
                           0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,
                           0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,
                          -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,
                          -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f};

    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);

    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(position_index, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}
```

render

```
void render()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(position_index);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);

    float c;
    if(bTime)
        c = (float)std::clock() * 2.0f / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    else
        c = 0.0f;

    glm::mat4 modelview = glm::rotate(-c * 50.0f, glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
    modelview = glm::translate(glm::vec3(0.0f + fTranslateX, 0.0f, -1.75f + fTranslateZ)) * modelview;
    glm::mat4 projection = glm::perspective(60.0f, 16.0f/9.0f, 0.10f, 100.0f); //perspective
    glm::mat4 MVP = projection * modelview;

    glUniformMatrix4fv(MVP_location, 1, GL_FALSE, &MVP[0][0]);

    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, 6);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(position_index);

    glutSwapBuffers();

    if(glGetError() != GL_NO_ERROR)
        exit(1);
}
```

#### The star image is:

[image: Star image]

#### Output:

[image: Screenshot]

Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I just disabled multisampling and now the points are square but still don't display the texture.

Comment: Does anything change if you use `vec2 (0.5, 0.5)` instead of `gl_PointCoord`? _(this should produce a white sprite)_. I think your texture's not loaded correctly. The alpha channel is implicitly **1.0** in an RGB texture and everything else is **0.0** initially, which explains what you are seeing.

Comment: I get white squares when I use vec2(0.5, 0.5). I can also assure you that the bmp instance loads the texture data from the bitmap correctly.

Comment: Okay, what version render context do you have? Is it compatibility or core? If it is compatibility, you may need to add `glEnable (GL_POINT_SPRITE)`. That is not necessary in a core profile, because that state was removed and is effectively *always* on in core.

Comment: glEnable (GL_POINT_SPRITE) made it work :), however, I have no Idea what compatibility or core mean. I use glew and freeglut. Can you explain?

Comment: Compatibility means legacy, a lot of stuff that's not hardware-based or that was not considered important to modern OpenGL was scheduled for removal when OpenGL 3.0 was created. OpenGL 3.1 came along and removed all of that stuff, but it was poorly implemented and finally in version 3.2 we got a proper solution: compatibility and core profiles. Compatibility profiles retain all legacy functionality and core profiles only let you use the modern set of OpenGL. In this case, the state `GL_POINT_SPRITE` is something specific to compatibility.

Comment: By the way, you get compatibility profiles unless you ask for core explicitly. This design ensures that old software written before compatibility / core were even a thing continues to work.

Answer (score 2):

In compatbility profiles (or any version of GL before 3.1), the behavior you want only occurs when `GL_POINT_SPRITE` is enabled. In a core profile, that state was removed, and `gl_PointCoord` always behaves as if `GL_POINT_SPRITE` were enabled.

To fix your problem, you must call `glEnable (GL_POINT_SPRITE)`.

Comment: So apparently I code in an old version of opengl? How do I start coding in "core profile"?

Comment: You can request a core profile from FreeGLUT (`glutInitContextVersion (4,3); glutInitContextProfile (GLUT_CORE_PROFILE);`), but a lot of things will break if you do that. Your code has to be 100% modern or it won't work once you go from compatibility (default) to core.